# Use specific version of Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I cloned a project where it comes with  `Jasmine: 1.3.1` specified  in package.json.

However I do other projects and I have installed 2.3.2  (installed with `npm install -g jasmine`)

```
npm view jasmine version
2.3.2
```

since there are compatibility issues, I can't run karma:unit because it keep using 2.3.2 instead of 1.3.1.

How can I force the project to use the karma which comes with the project?

Comment: How do you use jasmine? Because all my projects I test with grunt and/or mocha and use the project version, I never used jasmine globaly

Comment: My Jasmine actually comes as a dependency from Protractor which runs globally. the project uses grunt to run karma-jasmine. But when I print the jasmine version in a spec it shows 2.3.2 instead of 1.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I'd say uninstall the current `jasmine` and reinstall the specific version you like:

```
npm install -g jasmine@1.3.1
```

In case you want to record this somewhere in your project, you can add the following line to your project `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npm install -g jasmine@1.3.1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it worked...

Acording to https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine

"karma-jasmine": "~0.2.0"  = will install jasmine 2.x

"karma-jasmine": "~0.1.0"  = will install jasmine 1.x

So I decided to update the current 1.x tests to support jasmine 2.x
with

http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/upgrading.html